# how to Select automatically first value of dropdown in select input form?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

i'm trying to get the first selection from my list, the dropdown is showing all options, but the first option (the selected) is null.

Below my code

```js
<div class="form-group mb-6">
  <label class="form-label">{{ $trans('labels.department') }}</label>
  <select class="form-select" v-model="form.department_id">
    <option  :value="department.id" v-for="department in $page.departments">
      <p class="mt-1 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-500">
        {{ department.name }}
      </p>
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Is your dropdown not showing any items when you click on it?

Comment: is showing all options, but the first option (the selected) is null

Comment: Try to display  it upon the condition that its value is not null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try initializing it inside `created()`. It will select the first option from the loop.

ex.

```
created() {
  this.form.department_id = this.$page.departments[0].id
}
```